# Export/Require not working for Node.JS files

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

I have three JS files running under Node.JS.
 - server.js - primary server file
 - bidMgr.js - helper file
 - hand.js   - another helper file

They are back end server Express files. All are in the same directory.
hand.js exports a function named show:

```
    exports.show = function(hand) {...}
```

server.js exports a function named announceBid:

```
    exports.announceBid = function(newBid) {...}
```

bidMgr.js wants to call both of these functions.
So it requires each of the modules:

```
    const handModule = require(__dirname + "/hand.js");
    const serverModule = require(__dirname + "/server.js");
```

bidMgr.js calls the show function as shown:

```
    handModule.show(players['North'].hand);
```

But when bidMgr.js tries to call the announceBid function as shown:

```
    serverModule.announceBid(bidStr.charAt(0) + suit);
```

I get this error:
/home/Documents/FullStack/WebDevelopment/bid-server/bidMgr.js:212
    serverModule.announceBid(nextBid.level + nextBid.suit);
TypeError: serverModule.announceBid is not a function

I can't see any difference in how these functions are being exported and required.
Yet one works and the other does not.
I've looked at dozens of posts on StackOverflow and tried all the suggested solutions, without success.

My only guess is that the server.js code also needs to call functions exported by bidMgr.js.
That is, the server.js code includes the command:

```
    const bidMgr = require(__dirname + "/bidMgr.js");
```

Could the problem be a circular dependency?

Here are the snippets of code from each of the 3 files.
I have included in the snippets the require statements which are used, 
each exported function from the file, and how that function is called in a different file.
In summary:
- server.js exports announceBid(), which is called in bidMgr.js
- bidMgr.js exports processHumanBid(), which is called in server.js
- hand.js exports the Hand() constructor, which is called in bidMgr.js

All use the export/require semantics.
The call of Hand() in NewGame() in bidMgr.js works.
The call of announceBid() in processHumanBid() in bidMgr.js results in a error.

```
From server.js
---------------
// jshint esversion:6
const bidMgr = require(__dirname + "/bidMgr.js");

const express = require("express", "4.17.1");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


var connections = [],
    history = [],
    lastMessageId = 0,
    uptimeTimeout = 10 * 1000,
    totalRequests = 0;

function removeConnection(res) {
  var i = connections.indexOf(res);
  if (i !== -1) {
    connections.splice(i, 1);
  }
  console.log("Removed connection index " + i);
}

function broadcast(event, message) {
  message = JSON.stringify(message);
  ++lastMessageId;
  history.push({
    id: lastMessageId,
    event: event,
    message: message
  });

  connections.forEach(function (res) {
    sendSSE(res, lastMessageId, event, message);
  });
}

exports.announceBid = function(newBid) {
  const bidStr = newBid.level.toString() + newBid.suit;
  broadcast('bid', bidStr);
}


From bidMgr.js
---------------
// jshint esversion:6

// Require the card module
const card = require(__dirname + "/card.js");

// Require the deck module
const deck = require(__dirname + "/deck.js");

// Require the hand module
const handModule = require(__dirname + "/hand.js");

// Require the player module
const playerModule = require(__dirname + "/player.js");

const serverModule = require(__dirname + "/server.js");

function processHumanBid(bidStr) {
  const level = Number(bidStr.charAt(0));
  const suit = bidStr.charAt(1);

  nextBid = {suit: suit, level: level};
  console.log("Human bid " + nextBid.level + nextBid.suit + " for " + bidder);
  serverModule.announceBid(bidStr.charAt(0) + suit);
}

function newGame() {
  if (!allPlayersJoined) {
    console.log("Cannot start a game without all the players");
    return;
  }

  // Rotate the Dealer
  dealer = playerModule.getNextPlayer(dealer);
  console.log("Dealer is " + dealer);
  bidder = dealer;

  // Deal the cards
  var dealtHands = [];
  var bridgeHands = [];

  // Get the dealer to pass out all the cards into 4 piles
  dealtHands = deck.dealDeck();
  // Oh yeah, we are playing bridge. Create 4 bridge hands using these piles
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    bridgeHands[i] = new handModule.Hand(dealtHands[i]);
  };
}


From hand.js
------------
//jshint esversion:6

// Require the card module
const suitModule = require(__dirname + "/suit.js");

// Require the card module
const card = require(__dirname + "/card.js");

exports.Hand = function(dealtCards) {
  this.handCards = [...dealtCards];
  this.handCards.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.index < b.index) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.index > b.index) {
      return 1;
    }
    // a must be equal to b
    return 0;
  });
  this.hcPts = calcHCP(dealtCards);
  calcDistribution(this, dealtCards);
  this.totalPts = calcTotalPts(this);
  this.openingBid = calcOpenBid(this);
  this.player = null;
};
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Yes, the problem was a circular export/require dependency. There are several workarounds and hacks suggested in Stack Overflow. But ultimately the right answer is to restructure the code to make the circular dependency go away.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you don't use from call a function in the server.js (announceBid). for send response to client you can use a file this like:

apiResponse.js :

```
'use sctrict';
var HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes');

exports.sendSucces = function (res, data) {
    try {
        if (res) {
            if(data)
                res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(data);
            else
                res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        //log error
    }
}
```